# My keyframes get disappeared

Tags: keyframes

I am animating a gaming movie (Minecraft ) movie. When I started to use blender I used a character rig and I turned on auto key frame button and I selected a bone and bended it and I took the key frame pointer and placed it at 50. I took another bone and suddenly all key frames get disappeared and when I click the play button there are no key frames not in dope sheet. Please help so that no key frame get disappeared.

Thanks

Comment: Please use commas, periods and separated sentences to make your post more readable.

Comment: If all keyframes disappeared after you selected another bone and you have Dope Sheet to display only keyframes for selected objects then it's just because all the keyframes are on the unselected object. Select the first bone you animated before, make sure Dope Sheet is selected in the editor's header for displaying keyframes for objects and not something else.